# .htaccess Redirect / Rewrite with wildcards

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

Over the past year I have been using a WordPress theme that has forced me to incorporate a series of 301 redirects in order to allow users to view subsequent page through the page navigation.  That is, the main page’s URL would be http://example.com, when the user presses the page navigation arrow http://example.com/page/2/ is attempted to be loaded, but in order to view the content the user must be redirected to http://example.com/main/page/2/

```
Redirect 301 http://example.com/page/*/ http://example.com/main/page/*/
```

The following code works once the user is on a page other than page one and uses the page navigation, but not if they start on main page.  That is if the user is on http://example.com/main/page/2/ and use the page navigation they will be properly redirected to http://example.com/main/page/3/. However if they are on the main page and attempt to use the page navigation they will be sent to http://example.com/page/2/  Any ideas?

Comment: I remember Wordpress wasn't that bad for handling permalinks / pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Redirect` directive should be

```
Redirect 301 /page http://example.com/main/page
```

`Redirect` does not support full pattern matching like `RedirectMatch` and so doesn't recognize `*` but it can still handle simple prefix-matching i.e. anything after `/page` automatically gets appened to your target URL. And, like in my example above, the old URL path starts with a `/`.